# SQL неизвестная ошибка

Tags: 1с, sql-server-2005

Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в SQL. Я работаю с программой, которая напрямую связана с SQL 2005, то есть база данных работает на SQL 2005.
Когда программа дает сообщение "SQL неизвестная ошибка", можно ли в этом случае с помощью запроса в SQL 2005 устранить ошибку?
Пожалуйста, если вам нетрудно, ответьте. Если можно, запросы или что нужно для этого, пишите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, уважаемый [[@Армен](/users/5006/%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD)](/users/5006/%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD), нельзя. Судя по всему, Ваша программа содержит ошибку. Или база данных создана с ошибками. Вам нужно обратиться к разработчикам программы или к администратору базы данных, указав им при каких Ваших действиях программа возвращает сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с первым ответом.
Но если не удастся связаться с разработчиками, посмотрите в отладке, где именно ошибка происходит (может параметр не верный передается или еще что - это 1С все-таки).